# How to fill this jagged array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When outside of the function scope, `Tiles[[]]` loses all of it's values.

```
var Tiles= [[]];
function drawGrid(){
    Grid=true;
    // for the amout of rows
    for (let rowcount = 0; rowcount < amountOfrows; rowcount++) {
        ctxB.lineWidth = 1;
        
        // filling the rows
        // check for (un)even
        if(rowcount%2==0){
            for (let boxcount = 0; boxcount < amountOfHorBoxes; boxcount++) {
                ctxB.strokeStyle = "black";
                ctxB.fillStyle = "white";
                ctxB.beginPath();
                ctxB.rect(addHorBox, addVertBox, boxsize, boxsize);
                ctxB.fill();
                ctxB.closePath();
                ctxB.stroke();
                Tiles[rowcount[boxcount]]={x1: addHorBox, y1: boxsize*rowcount, x2: addHorBox+boxsize, y2: boxsize*(rowcount+1)};
                //console.log('Tiles:',Tiles[rowcount[boxcount]]);
                
                addHorBox+=boxsize;
            }
        }else{
            for (let boxcount = 0; boxcount < amountOfHorBoxes; boxcount++) {
                ctxB.strokeStyle = "black";
                ctxB.fillStyle = "white";
                ctxB.beginPath();
                ctxB.rect(addHorBox+boxsize/2, addVertBox, boxsize, boxsize);
                ctxB.fill();
                ctxB.closePath();
                ctxB.stroke(); 
                Tiles[rowcount[boxcount]]={x1: addHorBox, y1: boxsize*rowcount, x2: addHorBox+boxsize, y2: boxsize*(rowcount+1)};
                //console.log('Tiles:',Tiles[rowcount[boxcount]]);

                addHorBox+=boxsize;
            }
        }
        addHorBox=0;
        addVertBox+=boxsize;
    }
}
```

I haven't fully been able to check if I fill up the array properly, but regardless, it doesn't hold the values outside of it's scope. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you are accessing the Tiles array like so:

```js
Tiles[rowcount[boxcount]]={x1: addHorBox, y1: boxsize*rowcount, x2: addHorBox+boxsize, y2: boxsize*(rowcount+1)};
```

So the index you are using is the value stored at the `boxcount` property of `rowcount`, i.e the same as doing:

```js
let index = rowcount[boxcount];
Tiles[index]={x1: addHorBox, y1: boxsize*rowcount, x2: addHorBox+boxsize, y2: boxsize*(rowcount+1)};
```

Since the value of `rowcount[boxcount]` is undefined, you're storing your object in `Tile[undefined]`.

In order to access the two dimensional array, you need to do this:

```js
Tiles[rowcount][boxcount]={x1: addHorBox, y1: boxsize*rowcount, x2: addHorBox+boxsize, y2: boxsize*(rowcount+1)};
```

Also, you only have one row available to you initially, as you initialise you array like so: `Tiles = [[]];`

What I would recommend is to initialise `Tiles` as an empty array: `Tiles = [];`

Then for each row, push a new empty array into `Tiles`:

```js
for (let rowcount = 0; rowcount < amountOfrows; rowcount++) {
        ctxB.lineWidth = 1;
        Tiles.push([]);
        ...
}
```

Comment: How come it only works for rowcount being 0, and doesn't work for anything above? Tiles[0][..] and not Tiles[1+][..]?

Comment: for every new row you need to do `Tiles.push([])`